# reduce two group in java streaming api

Tags: java-8, java-stream

i want to group the item element according to date such that , if item object's date is greater than present date then , it will fall into futuredate group and if date is less than present date then it will fall into pastdate
 and then i want to reduce on these group so that i can get aggregate qty,price of these group, further aggregate value returned from  pastdate group shold sit in oldPrice and oldQty of object

```
 public class Item {        
            private String name;
            private int qty;
            private int oldQty;
            private BigDecimal price;
            private BigDecimal oldPrice;
            Private Date date;

            //constructors, getter/setters
        }


Map<String, List<Item>> groupByP =
            items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy((row)->{
//logic to seperate items into two group based on date
}));
```

How to proceed after this

Comment: So what exactly are you having trouble with? The logic to seperate your items into two groups?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to this, the first is first partition and later compute:
(this partitions, then return a Pair that holds the sum of all quantities and an average of the price)

```
 Map<Boolean, List<Item>> partioned = items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(item -> item.getDate().compareTo(now) > 0));

    partioned.get(Boolean.FALSE).stream()
            .map(item -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(item.getOldQty(), item.getOldPrice()))
            .reduce((entry1, entry2) -> {
                int sum = entry1.getKey() + entry2.getKey();
                BigDecimal averagePrice = entry1.getValue().add(entry2.getValue()).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(2));
                return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(sum, averagePrice);
            }).get();
```

The second us writing a custom collector, but I doubt it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split items into to groups you need to use partitioningBy collector.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public static class Item {
    private String name;
    private int qty;
    private int oldQty;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private BigDecimal oldPrice;
    private Date date;
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    List<Item> items = Lists.newArrayList();
    Map<Boolean, List<Item>> partitionedItems = items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(item -> item.getDate().after(new Date())));
}
```

In this case you'll get

```
Map<Boolean, List<Item>>
```

Now you can:

```
map.get(true)
```

returns a list of items that match the condition

```
map.get(false)
```

returns a list of items that don't match the condition

Having those two lists you can make any reduction you want.

Comment: What’s the point of `Lists.newArrayList()` compared to `new ArrayList<>()`?

Comment: @Holger I have this habit too, it's guava that made us write code like this. There is no point whatsoever.

Comment: @Eugene: I guess, these factory methods were created before Java 7, when we had to repeat the list’s element type when using `new`, but not for (factory) method invocations. Since the introduction of the “diamond operator”, it’s obsolete, but Guava will keep them, at least for a while, for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @Holger yup, exactly.

Comment: It's just an old habit. Trying to get rid of that but it's not so easy after 3 years with Java 6.